# Alert for unsaved changes before navigation in Svelte

Tags: javascript, alert, svelte

I have a Svelte application with form content. After a change in the form, I can trigger "unsaved change" alert when the page is refreshed. But after when i make a change in the form, if I try to navigate to another page with svelte navigation, I cannot handle unsaved change alert. How can I do this using Svelte Navigator?

Answer (score 2):

While his question was specifically asking about Svelte navigator, here's a solution for anyone using SvelteKit:

```js
beforeNavigate(({ cancel }) => {
  if (dirty) {
    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page? You have unsaved changes that will be lost.')) {
      cancel();
    }
  }
});
```

See the [beforeNavigate](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-beforenavigate) docs for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This currently appears to be [not directly supported](https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator/issues/45):

> I'm hesitant to add this to the library (for now) as it would require quite a bit of modification to the history module, as well as some new components (a Prompt component probably).
>
> Yout described solution using a proxy will work, but only on pushstate calls, which is only half the story. Browser back and forth buttons won't be intercepted here.
> That's why I'd recommend using a history module that already supports blocking. Take a look at the browser history from the [npm `history` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history). You can the use that history with svelte navigator (see [custom history section of readme](https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator#custom-history) and [custom hash history example](https://github.com/mefechoel/svelte-navigator/tree/main/example/custom-hash-history)).